# Cant chain two datasets together

Tags: python

I have the following data

```
a = {'x':1, 'z': 3}
b = {'y' : 2, 'z' : 4}
```

Now I would like to chain the two together. Therefore I do:

```
from collections import ChainMap
c = ChainMap(a,b)
```

This however throws the following error:

```
"Cannot import name ChainMap"
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: which version of python are you using? ChainMap is only in python 3.3 and newer. You can get a polyfill here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chainmap

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with ChainMap. The error is visible only if you are using an older version of Python3 --> 3.2 for instance.

Which Python are you using? I am using it with Python 3.5 and no problems are visible. If you try to use Py 3.2 or the 2.7 of course it will throw the mentioned error.

```
from collections import ChainMap

a = {'x': 1, 'z': 3}
b = {'y' : 2, 'z' : 4}

c = ChainMap(a,b)

print(c)
```

If fits for you, then please install latest version of Py3.x and you will see no issue.

Hope this solve your query. Have a nice day.